# How to show that two ergodic non-mutually singular measures equal

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $T: X\to X$ be continuous.  Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two Borel probability measures on $X$ which are ergodic for $T$.  If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not mutually singular, how to show that $\mu = \nu$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

The Ergodic Theorem tells you that for any $f : L^1(X)$ and for almost every $x$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i<n} f(T^ix)$$

equals *something*. Notice this limit *doesn't* depend on $\mu$ or $\nu$, whereas the *something* I'm alluding to does.

Can you leverage this (say by choosing $f = \chi_A$ to be a characteristic function) in order to prove $\mu = \nu$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks, and non-mutually singular guarantee the exsistance of an $x$ such that the average of $f(T^i x)$ equals to $\mu(A)$ and $\nu(A)$

Comment: You've got it! If this answered your question, you should mark it as such so that other users know how to spend their time